# php Post limited to 1000 variables

Tags: php, post

I've got a large form and I can see from firebug that all of the elements' values are being sent properly, but when I print_r($_POST) there are only 1000 variables displayed.  My max_post_size is set to 25M so I know that's not the issue and I searched through my php.ini for keywords like 'post' and 'max' and I didn't find anything.

1000 is only about 1/4 of the elements that I'm passing so obviously this is a pretty big issue for me, I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Only 1000 variables?

Comment: *(mouths)* ONE THOUSAND?

Comment: That's probably a limitation of the HTTP protocol (though I've never heard of it). Is there any way you can minimize the number of variables sent in your POST? I've never heard of a site that has OVER 9000 (had to be said) POST variables.

Comment: @lolwut - actually he's got 4000!!

Comment: I'd love to see this form, do you have a link?

Comment: you don't like your users much do you?

Comment: Same here, please send the link to the form.

Comment: lol, it's an internal site so unfortunately I can't give you guys a link.  Is sending that many a bad idea?  Security wont be an issue since it is internal, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: separate it in to pages, internal or not, it would still be a **** to fill in.

Comment: That's not the answer of your question. But I feel that I should give an advise. Can you try to simplify this form in some steps? It will be nice for the users and for you. ;)

Comment: I can't break it up, it's a setup table with many hidden elements that are altered as needed by a simple form.  This isn't a sign up form or anything like that.

Comment: bet you a million dollars you can break it in to separate pages. Perhaps you should post that as a question "how do I break this in to separate pages ..."

Comment: @Dagon it's not possible, nor practical.  My users would really hate me then - most of the elements are pre-populated by a CSV.

Comment: well i simply don't believe that. best of luck.

Comment: lol, how can you say that without even seeing the page? Sorry if I'm not doing a good enough job of describing the application but you just have to take my word for it.

Comment: Just to say, i have a form with more thant 3000 checkbox. Not pretty really, but the users has to select them either with mouse or with a barcode scanner. I do not see anything strange in this, it can be done better maybe.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I see what you did here.

```
max_input_vars, 1000
```

Introduced in order to prevent hash collision attack:
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/171-PHP-Vulnerability-May-Halt-Millions-of-Servers.html
But failed in 5.3.9:
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/175-Another-Serious-Security-Bug-on-PHP-539.html
So you should update to 5.3.10+ if that is problem.

Comment: Could be `suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000` also (if he's using Suhosin, of course).

Comment: @Crontab, could be, you're right, but all hosting companies should have updated to 5.3.10+ :)

Comment: I saw that about the max_input_vars and suhosin.post.max_vars settings but neither is in my php.ini.  I have 5.3.6 installed.

Comment: @jreed121 Have you tried turning it off and on again :) Checked here http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php and no word about limiting, sorry... If you can, update PHP. Did a quick test `for($i = 0; $i < 4000; $i++)
    $_POST[$i] = rand();` on few versions and no problem.

Comment: @webarto the lines don't even exist in the php.ini file.

Comment: Please check your `phpinfo()` for PHP version, whether suhosin is enabled and if applicable the values of `suhosin.post.max_vars` and `max_input_vars`.

Comment: I added max_input_vars = 2000 and restarted the machine and it worked

Comment: This is still happening in the latest PHP packaged by yum in CentOS. Like @jreed121 I added the variable to the php.ini (it was missing) and restarted Apache, that did the job.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar situation; I could only POST the first 1000 elements of an array.

My solution was to `implode()` the array into one long string and `explode()` it on the server side.

`json_encode()` could probably work as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had that exact same problem of the 1000 variable limit using PHP v5.4.20.  Even though the php.ini file did not contain any such 'max_input_vars' line, I simply found a convenient place to slot it in under the top [PHP] section, added the line 'max_input_vars = 10000', restarted Apache and everything was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've figured out a solution using jquery

I did it like this

```
$("#single-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var table_data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(table_data);
  // ajax call to handle the data
}
```

[serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function will give the URL encoded strings of all form data and in PHP file just use the function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the string into variables.