# CSRF issue crops up when data reaches certain amount

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, csrf

i've got csrf integrated throughout an entire app. no problems anywhere until today when working with a client to show them around. the area in question allows a user to search, select a subset (or all) of the items represented, and then move forward to do some data work with them.

it works totally fine until you hit ~70 records. if you've selected > 70  of the items and click the button to proceed then the function being called throws back the CSRF error `The action you have requested is not allowed.`

if I remove items to get below 70 then it works again. if I have the csrf token printed to the console it still shows up accurately when attempting to submit the 70+ items array.

i'm in Codeigniter using jQuery.

thanks for any input!

best,

Comment: Possibly related to the max post values you've configured to allow (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505192/php-post-limited-to-1000-variables), 70 records (with possibly multiple fields per record) can quite add up.

Comment: Ahhhh hadn't even considered that. Great idea. Will try it out and get back to you!

Comment: so i ran `phpinfo();` to see ensure I was editing the right `php.ini` file. got the following info in the output: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf` and 
`Loaded Configuration File /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini`. I then proceeded to edit *both* of them to make certain that the `max_input_vars` would be updated to 10000 instead of 1000. `phpinfo()` is still showing that the default value of 1000 is what is being read/seen. I stopped and restarted Apache, too, in case there was issue there. any ideas on why it isn't taking?

Comment: Do you have an _"Scan this dir for additional .ini files"_ or _"Additional .ini files parsed" _? Might be there. Also, grep recursively in your webserver config and .htaccess files, it's `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, so configurable there.

Comment: good and bad news. bad: still no luck locally. i'll try the above later this evening when i have a chance to toy a bit. good news: was able to change it on production server and voila! can you convert your comment to an answer so i can mark it as correct? thanks a bunch! will post re: local deal tonight or tomorrow, too. would love to figure out / know more about that situation as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [400 Bad Request - request header or cookie too large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524396/400-bad-request-request-header-or-cookie-too-large)

Comment: @PaulSweatte How are those duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to troubleshoot:

- Check how the data is being stored in the session
- If the data is being stored in the session, check the cookie of different requests
- If the cookie size changes based on the data set, it may be reaching the limit
- The limit varies by browser, so compare across browsers

**References**

- [PHP Sessions with disabled cookies, does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572134/1113772)