# Insert multiple rows into mysql database (items separated by comma)

Tags: php, mysql

need help...!!!
i have 2000 number of values like (3458,1356,....n) 
i want to post them from html input field as $_POST['roll']; along with few other columns which has similar values like board (dhaka,dhaka,dhaka) .. i want to insert them into database with php at once not one by one..

NOTE: i know there is a way to insert multiple rows but it will be time consuming to create that query for 2000 values.. so i want to use 2000 values at once with comma..

result should be like this

```
  +---------+-------------+
  |  board  |    roll     |
  +---------+-------------+
  |   dhaka |    3456     |
  |   dhaka |    4574     |
  |   dhaka |    6357     |
  |   dhaka |    2467     |
  +---------+-------------+
```

i am using this query to post single row at a time

```
 $board = $_POST['board'];
 $roll = $_POST['roll'];    
 $query = "INSERT INTO `host`.`result` (`board`, `roll`) VALUES ('$board','$roll') "
```

Comment: Do you already have a CSV of this data?

Comment: You'll also very likely come up against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505192/php-post-limited-to-1000-variables

Comment: use a loop, can explode the data into array then loop it.

Answer (score 1):

At first,
you can use php `explode()` function to make an php array. Then you INSERT your data using loop depending on Array size.

Code Example :

```
$roll = array();
$board = array();

$roll = (explode(",",$_POST['roll']));
$board = (explode(",",$_POST['board']));

$arraySize = sizeof($roll);

for($i=0; $i<$arraySize ; $i++){
   $query = "INSERT INTO `host`.`result` (`board`, `roll`) VALUES ($board[$i],$roll[$i]) "
}
```