# Why am I only getting back the first 1000 lines of JSON using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to troubleshoot a project for work (and unfortunately, I can't post the code from said project here). In doing so, I seem to have come across some sort of 'limitation' with the amount of data being returned from a JSON object using an AJAX POST request and PHP to echo back the results. I seem to be only getting the first 1000 lines back, but when I log the object, I get the full 2000 line object.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Here is my code:

**JS and Ajax request**

```
var payload = {
  "a": {}
};
for (i = 0, len = 2000; i < len; i++) {
  payload["a"][i] = {
    "b": "test",
  }; 
}
//logs 2000 line object
console.log(payload);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: payload,
    success: function(response) {
      // logs 1000 line object
      console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
header('content-type: application/json');

$post = json_encode($_POST);
echo $post;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a php limit, read here mate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505192/php-post-limited-to-1000-variables#9505230

Comment: You are my hero! I read so many articles talking about size limits, but nothing mentioned max_input_vars.   Thank You!!

Comment: Not a problem, have fun.